# Using foreign keys with multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have a problem with creating a database. My fictional problem is to create database for tracking volleyball games. It should contain information about players (team they play in, one player can play only in one team), and played games( every game contains 6 players in each team).

I wanted to create following tables :

- Player(Id P,Name,Surname,Team_Name F) ;
- Team(Team_Name P,Coach);
- Game(Date, Team1 F,Team2 F,Player1_Team1 F,...Player2_Team2 F,Player1_Team2 F,...,Player2_Team2 F).

I wanted that Team1 and Team2 are foreign keys Team_Name from Team table. Here is my attempt, I get that foreign key is incorrectly formed. I will be very glad for help.

```
CREATE TABLE Team (
    Team_Name varchar(20)  NOT NULL,
    Coach varchar(20)  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Team_pk PRIMARY KEY (Team_Name)
);


CREATE TABLE Game (
    id int  NOT NULL,
    Data date NOT  NULL,
    Team1 varchar(20)   NOT NULL,
    Team2 varchar(20)  NOT NULL,
    Score int  ,
    D1_Player1 int  NOT NULL,
    D1_Player2 int  NOT NULL,
    D1_Player3 int  NOT NULL,
    D1_Player4 int  NOT NULL,
    D1_Player5 int  NOT NULL,
    D1_Player6 int  NOT NULL,
    D2_Player1 int  NOT NULL,
    D2_Player2 int  NOT NULL,
    D2_Player3 int  NOT NULL,
    D2_Player4 int  NOT NULL,
    D2_Player5 int  NOT NULL,
    D2_Player6 int  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Game_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Player (
    Id int  NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(30)  NOT NULL,
    Surname varchar(30)  NOT NULL,
    Team_Name varchar(20)  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Player_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


ALTER TABLE Player ADD CONSTRAINT DZ
    FOREIGN KEY (Team_Name)
    REFERENCES Team (Team_Name)  
;


ALTER TABLE Game ADD CONSTRAINT MD
    FOREIGN KEY (Team1, Team2)
    REFERENCES Team (Team_Name, Team_Name)  
;


ALTER TABLE Mecz ADD CONSTRAINT MZ
    FOREIGN KEY (D1_Player1, D1_Player2, D1_Player3, D1_Player4, D1_zPlayer5, D1_Player6, D2_Player1, D2_Player2, D2_Player3, D2_Player4, D2_Player5, D2_Player6)
    REFERENCES Player (id, id, id, id, id, id, id, id, id, id, id, id)  
;
```

Comment: Please edit your Question so as to add a tag for which form of SQL you are using, i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL-Server`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add one by one all foreign keys.

> ```
> ALTER TABLE Game  ADD CONSTRAINT MZ
>     FOREIGN KEY (D1_Player1)
>     REFERENCES Player (id)  
> ;
>
> ALTER TABLE Game  ADD CONSTRAINT MZ2
>     FOREIGN KEY (D1_Player2)
>     REFERENCES Player (id)  
> ;
>
> ALTER TABLE Game  ADD CONSTRAINT MZ3
>     FOREIGN KEY (D1_Player3)
>     REFERENCES Player (id)  
> ;
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f099cfb164e70cf22e933777b211ae37)*

Comment: thanks you made my day! Know it works like a charm. To understand it better my didn't work because Foreign Key(Player1,...Player6) in fact wanted to create just one foreign key with multiple same columns not few foreign keys?